# Mojolicious, Mojo::DOM select tag by contains text

Tags: perl, parsing, css-selectors, mojolicious

Is there analog ":contains()"(JQuery, JSoup) selector in Mojolicious?

Selector ":contains('text') ~ td + td" work in JQuery and JSoup. How can I convert it to Mojolicious selector?

http://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/

> Description: Select all elements that contain the specified text.
>
> version added: 1.1.4jQuery( ":contains(text)" ) text: A string of text
>   to look for. It's case sensitive.

http://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/select/Selector.html

> :contains(text)   elements that contains the specified text. The search
>   is case insensitive. The text may appear in the found element, or any
>   of its descendants.

Mojolicious analog?

Comment: A cursory glance at the [docs](http://mojolicio.us/perldoc/Mojo/DOM/CSS) suggests there isn't a direct equivalent. You may need to examine the element's text separately.

Comment: Uh yeah, the first link is the exact same one I linked to (and the second is just a mirror). I'm saying since the docs don't say that there is one, then there probably *isn't* one.

Comment: not mirror. I use Mojolicious (5.79, Tiger Face). From version to version methods may differ. For example I use 'all_contents' in my script https://metacpan.org/pod/release/SRI/Mojolicious-5.79/lib/Mojo/DOM.pm In latest release there is not such method https://metacpan.org/pod/release/SRI/Mojolicious-6.01/lib/Mojo/DOM.pm RTFM it's not the answer. You just confirmed what said in docs.

Comment: @user3439968 no one is telling you to RTFM, you're being belligerent to someone who's trying to help you.

Comment: Sorry. Trying run you code.

Answer (score 5):

Untested, but I would go in the direction of

```
$dom->find('*')
    ->grep(sub { $_->all_text =~ /text/ })
    ->map('following', 'td')
    ->map('find', 'td')
```

(if you have something more specific before your `:contains`, like at least a tag name selector, then replace the `*` with that, which should greatly help the performance).

Comment: Direction is right. But I can't use second map this way.
_Can't locate object method "find" via package "Mojo::Collection"_.  I think grep return collection of dom, then first map return collection of collection. Don't find good solution for now.

Comment: Find solution how to use map on map. map(...) -> flatten -> map(...). Or map('following','td') -> map( sub{ $_ -> map('find','td')}). First example better. Thanks for help.

Answer (score -1):

Few experiment with **hobbs** code and I can repeat JQuery, JSoup selector result:

```
:contains('some string') ~ td + td
```

Mojo:

```
$dom 
-> find('*')
-> grep(sub { $_ -> text =~ /some string/; })
-> map('following', '~ td + td') 
-> flatten;
```

But, I don't think it's universal and best way to do such select. Just for  start.

> **text**
>
> Extract text content from this element only (not including child
> elements), smart whitespace trimming is enabled by default.
>
> **flatten**
>
> Flatten nested collections/arrays recursively and create a new
> collection with all elements.